# Firebase Database - Can the creator read & write with it being false?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I was wondering if the creator of the database could read and write regardless of it being both set to false?

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

And if it is so that no one can read and write including the creator, how do I make it so that I can be the only one to read and write?

Answer (score 0):

With security rules like the ones you're showing, all direct access from mobile and web clients is fully rejected, regardless of how the user is authenticated in your app.

However, all backend SDKs, especially the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), that are initialized with a service account will always bypass security rules.  This means that code running in Cloud Functions, for example, will not be affected.  This account is not necessarily the "creator" of the database - it is just a [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/) account that's added to the project.

The Firebase console also bypasses security rules.

This means you can write backend services and API endpoints that work with the database on the end user's behalf, without granting them any direct access to the data.

If you want only one specific user, Authenticated by Firebase, to be able to read and write the data from a web or mobile app, you will have to code that into your security rules using the given UID of the account.